# Does Tony Hawk Pro Skater 5 have local split-screen multiplayer?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-5

Does Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 5 have **local split-screen multiplayer**?

Comment: I can't find any proof of split screen multiplayer... But I also don't see a definitive "there is no split-screen multiplayer".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The back of the case in a shop says - 1 Player (2-20 network players) - Meaning no local multiplayer.

Comment: Where's the angry mob with pitchforks at? Thanks for confirming.